Unable to create windows vm instance on google cloud
I'm currently trying to set up a Google VM instance with the following specifications:

NVIDIA T4 GPU
n1-standard-2 (2 vCPU, 1 core, 7.5 GB)
Windows Server with a 500GB SD disk

I need it to run quicl Unreal Engine and other programs for a few time for a design project. No matter what I try, I can't create the VM. I always encounter the same issue:

An n1-standard-2 VM instance with 1 nvidia-tesla-t4 accelerator is currently unavailable in the europe-west3-b zone. Alternatively, you can try your request again with a different VM hardware configuration or at a later time. For more information, see the troubleshooting documentation.

Any suggestions?
Additionally, is the Windows server the correct choice if I want to run a Windows image?
I've already requested an increase to the quota limits up to 1000GB, which in theory should have resolved the issue, but I keep encountering the same error.

Even though it seems that the GPU you are choosing is available for that zone it might be that Google itself does not has the necessary resources in that period of time to provision such resource.
Could you try in another region or a different vm size?

You can check if there is a log ZONE\_RESOURCE\_POOL\_EXHAUSTED  on the cloud logging, if it does, try to provision it in another region or create a reservation.
Alternatively, you can check the marketplace for unreal engine offering that are available.
